# asp.net dynamically loading assemblies

Tags: asp.net, plugins, webforms, mef, .net-assembly

I'm trying to make some sort of plugin system for asp.net webforms using MEF.

So far I've come with a solution where the host website will search in its plugin folder to load other websites called **Module**. A module (plugin) is just another website project, so it has its own assemblies in its **bin** subfolder.

As you certainly already know, an ASP.NET application won't load dll outside its **bin** folder. So if I try to access a module page (eg: **plugins/MyModule/Page.aspx**). I'll get an error saying that the server can't load the assembly **MyModule**. I can throw the module's assembly in the main **bin** folder and everything will work, but I would like to keep all the module files in the same folder.

So I'm looking for a way to load assemblies outside the **bin** folder. I've tried messing with the web.config file but couldn't come with a working solution.

Then I came accross the **BuildManager** class and wrote this code :

```
string pluginPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "plugins");
foreach (string f in Directory.GetDirectories(pluginPath))
{
    string binPath = Path.Combine(f, "bin");
    if (Directory.Exists(binPath))
    {
        foreach (String file in Directory.GetFiles(binPath, "*.dll"))
        {
            Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom(file);
            BuildManager.AddReferencedAssembly(a);
        }
    }
}
```

It search the **plugin** folder for any other subfolder containing a **bin** folder and load the corresponding assemblies using the **BuildManager**. To make this code works I have to call it in the **PreApplicationStartMethod** of the **global.aspx** assembly.

Now when I navigate to the plugin page (**plugin/MyModule/Page.aspx**) it won't give me the previous error but the page is blank. I've checked the source and there is no html, nothing. I've tried to debug the page but the **Page_Load** method is never called. So I guess somehow the code behind **Page.aspx** is never called.

Edit:

So after searching a bit more I found a solution there:

[BuildManager Resolving Page Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199237/buildmanager-resolving-page-inheritance)

When I load a module assembly, I store its reference in a dictionnay.
Then in the event handler to **AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve** I return the corresponding module assembly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the same problem. I fixed by resolving assembly as below

```
protected virtual void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //...

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
    }

    System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        var currentAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

        foreach (var assembly in currentAssemblies)
        {
            if (assembly.FullName == args.Name || assembly.GetName().Name == args.Name)
            {
                return assembly;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I did come up with the same solution